# Curl (php) post variables not received form submitting

Tags: php, post, curl

I'm designing application for work. It should take the data provided and insert into form provided below, and automatically submit it.
There are no issues on any other page, I'm able to login, save cookies, read them, go to other links on the same site. 
The problem I'm having is occurring on the page with the form, specifically, curl executes and fetches the page, but the post data is not sent.(data is sent as array, also tried urlencoded string)
It think there might be a problem with the way the form is structured(code below).
Also, the site with the form is not mine, but i will provide headers and post variable that are asked.

So to begin. 
Form:

```
<form action="newFault" method="GET" id="typeForm">
<div style="margin:5px">
Tip smetnje:
<select name="type" id="type">
<option value="SVA" selected>SVA VA</option>
<option value="SNBS">SNBS - NBSA</option>
<option value="SULL">SULL - ULL</option>
</select>
</div>
</form>

<div>
<form method="POST" action="createFault" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="SVA">
<table class="tableLight" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" style="margin: 5px;">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align: right">Virtual account code:</td>
<td><input name="accountCode" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>konos</th>
<th style="text-align: right">Kontakt osoba:</th>
<td><input name="param.konos" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>tel</th>
<th style="text-align: right">Telefon:</th>
<td><input name="param.tel" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>tfx</th>
<td style="text-align: right">Telefax:</th>
<td><input name="param.tfx" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>eml</th>
<td style="text-align: right">E-mail:</td>
<td><input name="param.eml" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>vrkv</th>
<th style="text-align: right">Vrsta:</th>
<td><input name="param.vrkv" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>lpb</th>
<td style="text-align: right">Lokalni pozivni broj:</td>
<td><input name="param.lpb" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>idkod</th>
<th style="text-align: right">nesto pristupa:</th>
<td><input name="param.idkod" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>ugbrz</th>
<td style="text-align: right">brzina:</td>
<td><input name="param.ugbrz" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>iatk</th>
<th style="text-align: right; ">Name:</th>
<td><textarea name="param.iatk" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>dkk</th>
<td style="text-align: right">Datum koji odredi krajnji korisnik (ukoliko je to primjenjivo):</td>
<td><input name="param.dkk" size="60"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>opkv</th>
<th style="text-align: right">Opis kvara:</th>
<td><textarea name="param.opkv" cols="40"></textarea></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" style="text-align: right">Dokumentacija u TIFF formatu:</th>
<td><input type="file" name="attachment"></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td colspan="2">
<input type="submit" value="Pozovi">
```

PHP code:

```
function saljipostom()
{
$postdata = 'type=SVA&accountCode=101010&param.konos=osoba&param.tel=016000840&param.tfx=&param.eml=&param.vrkv=vrsta&param.lpb=&param.idkod=02637992641&param.ugbrz=&param.iatk=imekorisnika&param.dkk=&param.opkv=opis&attachment=&submit=Pozovi';
$fields = array(
'type'=>'SVA',
'accountCode'=>'101010',
'param.konos'=>'osoba',
'param.tel'=>'016000840',
'param.tfx'=>'',
'param.eml'=>'',
'param.vrkv'=>'vrsta',
'param.lpb'=>'',
'param.idkod'=>'02637992641',
'param.ugbrz'=>'',
'param.iatk'=>'imekorisnika',
'param.dkk'=>'',
'param.opkv'=>'opis',
'attachment'=>''
);
$polje = $fields;
foreach ( $fields as $key => $value) 
{
    $post_items[] = $key . '=' . urlencode($value);
}
$post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://something.something/ui/ganimed/b2b/newFault?type=SVA");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'curl/cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'curl/cookies.txt');

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
unset($ch);

$page = str_get_html($result);
echo $page;
}
```

output is echoed to .js

Response header from curl:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 08:05:17 GMT Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8 Content-Language: en-US Vary: Accept-Encoding Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Firebug says post fields are:

```
typeSVA
accountCode
param.konos
param.tel
param.tfx
param.eml
param.vrkv
param.lpb
param.idkod
param.ugbrz
param.iatk
param.dkk
param.opkv
attachment
```

Headers
IN firebug

```
Response Headers
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Language    en-US
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/plain
Date    Thu, 24 Jan 2013 12:52:46 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=15, max=100
Location    https://something.something/ui/something/b2b/faults?type=SVA&guid=40898022-1b33-42ab-a9f2-696cc5f70950
```

Request Headers

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=DD0148C1D1701FA237704C42DE093687.node1
Host    something
Referer https://something.something/ui/something/something/newFault?type=SVA
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
```

QUestion: The problem I'm having is occurring on the page with the form, specifically, curl executes and fetches the page, but the post data is not sent, ie. form is not accepting it(data is sent as array, also tried urlencoded string) ANy ideas?

Anything else you need just ask.

Comment: I gave up on this. If anyone finds themselves in similar situation, i suggest give it up trying to do it with curl. Because of the ajax written form I couldn't do it with curl. Recently I had similar project but this time i wrote it in python/mechanize and it worked like a charm. So python is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a index.php file and place the following code there:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://localhost/curltest/ind.php';

$paramsarray = array(
    'name' => '',
    'age' =>  24,
);

$params = $query = http_build_query($paramsarray, '', '&');



$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
));
$ress = curl_exec($ch);

echo $ress;

if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
    echo 0;
} else {
    echo 1;
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

Now create a second PHP file named `ind.php`. Place it in the same project.

Write following code in that file:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Run the index.php file and you will get output such as:

```
Array ( [name] => [age] => 24 ) 1
```

Which shows that the empty Post fields are submitted to the `ind.php` page using curl.

Comment: Good idea. I'll try that when i get home. So that should not be the problem. 
Any idea what else can i try? Ill post headers when i use the form so you can see what is happening in normal form use.

Comment: To make it easier to read the output of `print_r()` you use first print `<pre>`. You could also close the tag, although that's not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://foo.com/';

    $paramsarray = array(
            'name' => ' Test',
            'age' =>  24,
            'preferences' => array(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    )

$params = http_build_query($paramsarray);


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
            echo 0;
    } else {
            echo 1;
    }

    curl_close ($ch);
```

try this you can  use the `http_build_query()` function to make an array into the required string format. and then post to the url using curl

Comment: I told you up there that I tried sending as string as well as array, no go in both cases.